# Создать один массив из двух, где в массиве album есть userId и есть массив пользователей с уникальным id

Tags: javascript, arraylist

[image: Пример как должно выглядеть]

Создать один массив из двух, где в массиве album есть userId и есть массив пользователей с уникальным id.

```
const arrayOfAlbums = [
 {
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "quidem molestiae enim"
},
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 2,
"title": "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa"
},
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 3,
"title": "omnis laborum odio"
},
]

const arrayOfUsers = [
 {
"id": 1,
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Lamer Pajam",
"username": "Alex",
"email": "sanasj@qdw.re",
},
]

const mergedArrShouldBe = [
  {
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "quidem molestiae enim",
"author": "Lamer Pajam",
},
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 2,
"title": "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa",
"author": "Lamer Pajam"
},
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 3,
"title": "omnis laborum odio",
"author": "Lamer Pajam"
},
]
```

Comment: "По этим картинкам, по этим картинкам, которые мы рисовали для вас, Придумайте сами, придумайте сами, придумайте сами веселый рассказ." И почему нет слов "пожалуйста" и "очень надо"?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите кодом (текстом) примеры двух исходных массивов и пример целевого массива, чтобы желающим ответить не пришлось набирать эти примеры по картинкам. Старайтесь максимально облегчить работу людям, которые возьмутся тратить на помощь вам своё время.

Comment: Сильно лучше не стало, все равно нужно всматриваться что там за Array of album и Array of users. Поэтому проголосовал "оставить закрытым".

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this
it's a tricky one cuz id of user override id of album so i decide to create a new
obj without id [just a name] and merge it wiht album

```
const mergedArray = arrayOfAlums.data.reduce((acc, album) => {
          arrayOfUsers.data.map(user => {
            if (user.id === album.userId) {
              const userWithoutId = {author: user.name}
              acc.push({...album, ...userWithoutId})
            }
            return user
          })
          return acc
        },[])
```

Not good way

```
const mergedArray = arrayOfAlums.map(album => ({...album, ...arrayOfAuthors.find(author => author.id === album.userId)}))
```